# How to remove woocommerce unnecessary functions which cause load?

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, plugins, woocommerce

I have woo-commerce plugin installed. I use woo-commerce only for external/affiliate products selling. But there is lot more function their on that plugin such as, Add to cart functions, registrations, coupons, etc. I dont need them actually. All i need is the front page, single product page with a **BUY NOW** button in it and back-end settings for it.

How do i turn of all unnecessary woocommerce functions which causing high load time?

Comment: There is no shortcut for it. All you have to do is trace the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one solution of it make a copy of woocommerce in your theme and keep only those file which you want to use ...and don't touch the plugin folder. only
just override it ....
   if you do this then your theme call only those function with is overriding from your theme not all in your plugin folder ...

Comment: Hello Navnit, Thanks For Your Help, I think this is a great idea. My question is how do i execute this? I mean in which folder i should make copy of woocommerce and where to over-ride the file. Sorry i am newbie. My website is www.desigyan.com , Please take a look, As i only need css styles.

Comment: Noo problem just create a folder in your active theme name of folder is Woocommerce and just keep in this folder only those file which you want to execute ...

Comment: Thanks, Currently I don't have that much reputation to vote but i will try your suggestions

Comment: Hi, i tried it, no impact, But i really don't understand how it will work? i have now two copy of woocommerce. One in my theme folder on in plugin folder, so according to your should i start deleting unnecessary files from the folder which is on my active theme folder ? how that will going to help because all resources are still there on plugin's woocommerce folder. Thanks